# Google account 2FA only with HW security key?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, gmail, sms, yubikey

Is it possible to configure 2FA access to a Google account using only HW security key (e.g. Yubikey) without verification SMS code option ?

It seems that SMS confirmation code is still primary 2FA option and it cannot be disabled or removed;  but what if attacker hacks my Android phone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your Google Account to use [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) and install the Yubico Authenticator App either on your [Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yubico.yubioath) or additionally on your [PC](https://developers.yubico.com/yubioath-desktop/)

Its like using the Gooogle Authenticator but the secret is not stored on your phone but on the Yubikey. So if your phone is stolen they still need the Yubikey to enter your account.

You can use this combination for every Website that supports 2FA with TOTP.

But to do this, your need the Yubikey Neo and an phone which supports NFC.

Comment: This seems to be right solution. I am using Yubikey NEO so 2FA with TOTP should work fine with my NFC smartphone.

Comment: And of course you should always have backup solution in the case you lost your HW key - use backup HW key stored in different location or write down google backup codes and keep it safe somewhere